# Java: Can an encrypted UID embedded on a web page be effective?

Tags: java, encryption, uniqueidentifier

My boss wants me to adapt a Java webapp to effectively disable the ability to navigate within the Java webapp by typing URLs into the location bar.

I've come up with a couple of strategies to make this happen.

One thing I am thinking of is generating a unique ID number and printing it on the JSP in a hidden form field to send back to the server via an HTTP POST request.

I know that someone looking to play games can just save the page and submit the post form from the resulting static file.

I was thinking about encrypting the ID number, but I am wondering if there would be a point to doing that?   It would be decrypted server side the same as if the user clicked a navigation button or if a hackerish user viewed the source and used a script/static HTML page to send the ID number back to the server.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the point of such an endeavor in the first place?

Comment: You want to have a web app that doesn't behave like a web app?

Comment: The point is to force the user to use only buttons and links to navigate within the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the strategy used, but encryption of a UID is not a good solution on its own. The most important parts with any kind of security that relies on encryption are the protocol and the key management. Basically, if you cannot trust one of the two then your application is not safe. If the encrypted UID is just seen as a static variable, then anybody can simply copy the encrypted UID (as you mused in your question).

What you could do is to use an UID stored in a cookie and at the server. Use that to create a key (using a key derivation function). Now if there is a request, make sure that the request contains a unique number (e.g. session ID + counter). Now you can create a Message Authentication Code with the previously calculated key, base64 encode it and send it with the request. Then you verify this the MAC on the server side (using the key, the data and of course the MAC data).

Even this scheme is of course not capable of detering a hacker. For that you need at least to use a TLS connection to make sure that the UID (used to generate the key) cannot be read during transport. Basically, without TLS you cannot create a solution that is sufficiently secure to deter targeted man-in-the-middle attacks.